# Node Browser does not work properly

Tags: alfresco

I have a new content model and by it i create a new node called "organization" and that node will be saved under organizations folder.

After create a node i noticed that Node Browser and search Service will not be able to find my organization(s) nodes which are located in the organizations folder until i navigate to the organizations folder node.

Can any on help me ?

All of your replies are highly appreciated.

My Code Is:

```
                // Acquire organization folder
            Node organizationsFolder = new Node(NodeUtil
                    .acquireOrganizationsFolder(searchService));
            // current organization created
            currentOrganization = new Node(
                    nodeService.createNode(
                                    organizationsFolder.getNodeRef(),
                                    ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                                    QName.createQName(
                                                    Constants.DIGITAL_SERIES_SECURITY_MODEL_NAMEPSACE_PREFIX_STRING,
                                                    Constants.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION_STRING),
                                    Constants.SecurityModelQNames.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION,
                                    new HashMap<QName,Serializable>()).getChildRef());

            // PREPARE ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE ID
            Node organizationSeq = new Node(SequenceUtil.prepareSequence(
                    SequenceUtil.ORGANIZATION_SEQUENCE_NODE_NAME_STRING,
                    nodeService, searchService));

            // LOCK ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE
            if(!organizationSeq.isLocked()){
                lockService.lock(organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), LockType.NODE_LOCK);
                // GET THE NEXT SEQUENCE
                SequenceUtil.addCurrentSequence(organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), nodeService);
            }

            // PREPARE ORGANIZATION PROPERTIES
            Map<QName, Serializable> orgProps = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();

            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE ID
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID,
                            SequenceUtil.getCurrentSequence(
                                    organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), nodeService));
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION/CONTENT NAME PROPERTY
            orgProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                            currentOrganization).toString() + 
                    "_"+orgProps.get(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID)); 
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION NAME PROPERTY
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                            currentOrganization).toString());
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION DESCRIPTION
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
                            currentOrganization).toString());
            // UPDATE THE PROPERTIES TO AN ORGANIZATION NODE
            nodeService.setProperties(currentOrganization.getNodeRef(), orgProps);
            // UNLOCK 
            lockService.unlock(organizationSeq.getNodeRef());
```

Thanks
Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series Co.

Answer (score 2):

Strange, normally it should work.

The indexing process could be still active if you directly try to search the created content.

Can you post your code how you create the node?