# follow for "Nodes sometimes searched and others not seen ?"

Tags: alfresco

Appreciate:

Firstly, i would to thank you for your cares with this problem,

Overview:

THE PROBLEM IS TESTED IN THE BUILT-IN FUNCTIONALITY AND BY JAVA CODE AND THE RESULTS ARE THE SAME
NODES WILL NOT BE DISPLAYED ONCE THE ALFRESCO SERVER DOWN AND STARTED AGAIN EXCEPT I PASS TO COMPANY HOME FOLDER.

Problem:

I have a new content model, new dialogs. The main content model  is the organization model which extends from cm:content and have two properties one for organization name and other for organization description.

From the admin console i click in a new link called create organization and the create organization dialog will be invoked correctly and once i fill the data and i click the create/ finish button the organization will be created correctly.

Case 1:

now,all things are passed properly but once i shutdown the alfresco and start it up again, and once i go directly toward the node browser without passing on "company home" folder the node browser will not be able to see my new nodes.

Case 2:

now, all things are passed properly but once i shut down the alfresco and start it up again, and once i enter the company home folder and return back to the node browser the nodes created will be shown.

### Technical Details

My Content Model:

```
<description>Security Content Model</description>
<author>MOHAMMED AMR</author>
<version>1.0</version>

<imports>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/user/1.0" prefix="usr"/>
</imports>

<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="www.ds.alfresco.security.extension.com" prefix="sec" />
</namespaces>


<types>

    <type name="sec:organizationSequence">
        <title>Organization Sequence</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
         <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>sec:sequencable</aspect>
         </mandatory-aspects>   
    </type>

    <type name="sec:positionSequence">
        <title>Position Sequence</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
         <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>sec:sequencable</aspect>
         </mandatory-aspects>           
    </type>     

    <type name="sec:position">
        <title>Position</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="sec:positionId">
                <title>Position ID</title>
                <type>d:int</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sec:positionName">
                <title>Position Name</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sec:positionDescription">
                <title>Position Description</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
        </properties>               
        <associations>
            <child-association name="sec:suborindatesPositions">
                <source>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <many>false</many>
                </source>
                <target>
                    <class>sec:position</class>
                    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                    <many>true</many>
                </target>
                <duplicate>false</duplicate>
                <propagateTimestamps>true</propagateTimestamps>
            </child-association>
        </associations>
    </type> 

    <type name="sec:organization">
        <title>Organization</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="sec:organizationId">
                <title>Organization ID</title>
                <type>d:int</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sec:organizationName">
                <title>Organization Name</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sec:organizationDescription">
                <title>Organization Description</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>             
            <property name="sec:rootPosition">
                <title>Root Position</title>
                <type>d:noderef</type>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type> 
</types>

<aspects>
    <aspect name="sec:sequencable">
        <title>Capable To Have a Sequence</title>
        <parent>cm:content</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="sec:sequenceId">
                <title>Sequence</title>
                <type>d:int</type>
            </property>
            <property name="sec:sequenceName">
                <title>Sequence Name</title>
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </aspect>
</aspects>
```

---

My Java Code:

my java code will create the organization in two steps

The first step will create the organization node as without any metadata to give the user chance enter the user chance for enter the meta data for the organization from the dialog.

First Step:

```
    public final RetryingTransactionCallback<String> CreateOrganizationCallback 
                = new RetryingTransactionCallback<String>() {
        public String execute() throws Throwable {
            // ACQUIRE THE FOLDER NODE REF
            Node organizationsFolder = new Node(NodeUtil
                    .acquireOrganizationsFolder(searchService));
            // CURRENT ORGANIZATION CREATION
            currentOrganization = new Node(
                    nodeService.createNode(
                                    organizationsFolder.getNodeRef(),
                                    ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                                    QName.createQName(
                                            Constants.DIGITAL_SERIES_SECURITY_MODEL_NAMEPSACE_PREFIX_STRING,
                                            Constants.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION_STRING,namespacePrefixResolver),
                                    Constants.SecurityModelQNames.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION,
                                    new HashMap<QName,Serializable>()).getChildRef());
            return "";
        }
    };
```

Second Step:

```
    public final RetryingTransactionCallback<String> CreateOrganizationCallback = new RetryingTransactionCallback<String>() {
        public String execute() throws Throwable {

            // PREPARE ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE ID
            Node organizationSeq = new Node(SequenceUtil.prepareSequence(
                    SequenceUtil.ORGANIZATION_SEQUENCE_NODE_NAME_STRING,
                    nodeService, searchService));

            // LOCK ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE
            if(!organizationSeq.isLocked()){
                lockService.lock(organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), LockType.NODE_LOCK);
                // GET THE NEXT SEQUENCE
                SequenceUtil.addCurrentSequence(organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), nodeService);
            }

            // PREPARE ORGANIZATION PROPERTIES
            Map<QName, Serializable> orgProps = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();

            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION SEQUENCE ID
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID,
                            SequenceUtil.getCurrentSequence(
                                    organizationSeq.getNodeRef(), nodeService));
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION/CONTENT NAME PROPERTY
            orgProps.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                            currentOrganization).toString() + 
                    "_"+orgProps.get(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_ID)); 
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION NAME PROPERTY
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_NAME, 
                            currentOrganization).toString());
            // UPDATE ORGANIZATION DESCRIPTION
            orgProps.put(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
                    NodeUtil.extractNodeProperty(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_ORGANIZATION_ORGANIZATION_DESCRIPTION, 
                            currentOrganization).toString());
            // UPDATE THE PROPERTIES TO AN ORGANIZATION NODE
            nodeService.setProperties(currentOrganization.getNodeRef(), orgProps);
            // UNLOCK 
            lockService.unlock(organizationSeq.getNodeRef());

            return TO_ADMIN_CONSOLE_PAGE;
        }
    };
```

NOTE: WITHOUT JAVA CODE, THE BEHAVIOR WILL BE THE SAME WHEN YOU CREATE CONTENT FROM CUSTOM MODEL USING BUILT-IN FUNCTIONALITY WITHIN ALFRESCO

NOTE: DO NOT TEST THE PROBLEM IN THE BUILT-IN MODEL CAUSE THE BEHAVIOR WILL NOT BE SHOWN ANYMORE.

I'm waiting your replies.

Thanks for your help and all replies are highly appreciated.

Mohammed Amr
Senior System Developer
Digital Series Co.

Comment: Also, the namespace are registered with its prefix in the namespace service. I see that by tracing the code navigate the namespace prefixes and their associated uri(s).

Comment: Hi Mohammed, you shouldn't submit the same question multiple times. You have already asked more or less the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889886/node-browser-does-not-work-properly/6891820#6891820

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how to follow a question to set more details

Comment: @MohammedAmr: Can you please edit the question to make it more descriptive of this issue?

Comment: This is a bug :) and this is the link http://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-9803

Answer (score 1):

I think you're creating a node with no meta-data. That's why you can't search for it.

Try the following:

```
    Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>(10);
    props.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, "Testfile");

currentOrganization = new Node(
                    nodeService.createNode(
                                    organizationsFolder.getNodeRef(),
                                    ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                                    QName.createQName(Constants.DIGITAL_SERIES_SECURITY_MODEL_NAMEPSACE_PREFIX_STRING,                                    Constants.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION_STRING,namespacePrefixResolver),
                                    Constants.SecurityModelQNames.TYPE_SEC_ORGANIZATION,
                                    props);
```

The important part is that you are giving the cm:name meta-data to the node and providing the childname.

This is my code to create a node:

```
Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>(10);
                props.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, logFileName);
                ChildAssociationRef logRef = getNodeService().createNode(downloadFolder, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, logFileName), ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, props);
```

Comment: Yes Tahir, The first step is done by the above code but the second step will cover what you are talking about. Look at the second step after finish button clicked the complement code has been executed, you can see the code again

Comment: Look again to the code, you will see a meta-data properties. Also Tahir i use the built-in "create content" functionality to create a new organization and after that i shutdown and startup the alfresco server "two times" one of them the node browser finds the nodes after search by lucene with "prefix" and "uri" and the second time node browser could not find any node by using the lucene search with prefix and uri. Notice that i check and ensure that the spelling of lucene search is correct and the nodes have been created from type organization.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I think you need to start from scratch. Get the SDK, there is a java sample class which stores content. Use that one and if you see that you can't find the content, then your Alfresco instance is probably corrupt. Good luck!

Comment: Tahir, I use the alfresco create content built-in functionality and the results are the same !

Comment: I'm not saying the built-in functionality, use the sample code. Which writes a normal cm:content with some meta-data properties. Try that and check if you can find the node